# Get drive files stats (views/openings) | Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I've been searching the docs but I can't find anything.

The goal is to retrieve different stats from our files. Actually, we can retrieve almost everything we need, except for the document openings and document openings per user.

So here is the question: **How can I retrieve document views of a drive document (a G Sheet to be more precise) ? Can I segment it by user ?**

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK the Drive API does not provide a native way to track the number of times a document has been opened.

Comment: Not sure but take a look at Drive Activity

Comment: If you are Google Workspace administrator you might use the [Workspace Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/overview) to get info about the user activities.

Comment: Found the event "view" using Workspace Admin SDK need to try it now, thank you @RUben

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your goals are the following one:

- You want to retrieve document views
- Of a particular document (and you know it's id)
- Associated to a specific user

Please correct me if I get it wrong. If those are your goals, then you can use the Admin SDK as pointed out by [Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n) in the comments. Now I am going to detail how you can make such a request easily.

You could use the method [`activities.list()`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) to get a list with what you want. You only have to populate these four parameters:

| Parameter | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userKey | The user's email | Determine the user |
| applicationName | `drive` | Identifies the Google service |
| eventName | `view` | Designate the type of activity |
| filters | `doc_id=={MY DOCUMENT ID HERE}` | Filters by the document |

That configuration will provide you with your desired data. Leave a comment below if you need help creating that request in your own environment.

Comment: Thank you Jacques! Looks great. Let me try I come back here later.